# Appending filters to django models

Tags: python, django

**Context**

Hey guys,

So let's say I have two models: **Person** and **Attribute** connected by a ManyToMany relationship (one person can have many attributes, one attribute can be shared by many people)

```
class Attribute(models.model):
  attribute_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  attribute_type = models.CharField(max_length=1)

class Person(models.model):
  article_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  attributes = models.ManyToManyField(Attribute)
```

- Attributes can be things like hair colour, location, university degree.
- So for example, an attribute may have an 'attribute_name' of 'Computer Science' and an 'attribute_type' of 'D' (for degree).
- Another example would be 'London', 'L'.

**The Issue**

On this web page, users can select people by attributes. For example, they may want to see all people who live in London and who have degrees in both History and Biology (all AND relationships).

I understand that this could be represented in the following (breaks for legibility):

```
Person.objects
.filter(attributes__attribute_name='London', attributes__attribute_type='L')
.filter(attributes__attribute_name='History', attributes__attribute_type='D')
.filter(attributes__attribute_name='Biology', attributes__attribute_type='D')
```

However, the user could equally ask for users who have four different degrees. The point being, **we don't know how many attributes the user will ask for in the search function.**

**Questions**

- As such, which would be the best way to append these filters if we don't know how many, and what types of attributes the user will request?
- Is appending filters like this the best way?

Thanks!

Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could obtain all attributes selected by the user and then iterate over:

```
# sel_att holds the user selected attributes.

result = Person.objects.all()

for att in sel_att:
    result = result.filter(
        attributes__attribute_name=att.attribute_name, 
        attributes__attribute_type=att.attribute_type
    )
```

Comment: I think this is the best you're going to do with this data design, but I'd personally start with `result = Person.objects.all()` before iterating through the `sel_att` list - better readability IMO. For the OP - if you can choose a different data model, you might benefit from doing so. Google 'entity attribute value' for some discussion.

Comment: Perfect. I got this to work! Thanks, Raydel. And Peter, thanks a lot for the tip - I'll get reading!

Answer (score 0):

Use the Q module for complex lookups.

For example:

```
from django.db.models import Q
Person.objects.get(Q(attributes__attribute_name='London') | Q(attributes__attribute_name='History')
```

Within a `QuerySet` a `|` acts as an OR and a `,` acts as an AND, pretty much as expected.

The problem with chanining filters is you can only implement an AND logic between them, for a complex AND, OR, NOT logic Q would be the better way to go.

Comment: I tried Q, but this would show me all people with at least one of these attributes, whereas I want people with *all* of them. Secondly, this query in particular doesn't work with an ampersand, unfortunately - when I try it with an ampersand it returns no results.